# Where do untagged Docker images come from?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm creating some very simple Docker containers. I understand that after each step a new container is created. However, when using other Dockerfiles from the Hub I don't wind up with untagged images. So where do they come from? After browsing around online I have found out how to remove them but I want to gain a better understanding where they come from. Ideally I would like to prevent them from ever being created.

From their documentation

> This will display untagged images, that are the leaves of the images
>   tree (not intermediary layers). These images occur when a new build of
>   an image takes the repo:tag away from the IMAGE ID, leaving it
>   untagged. A warning will be issued if trying to remove an image when a
>   container is presently using it. By having this flag it allows for
>   batch cleanup.

I don't quite understand this. Why are builds taking the `repo:tag` away from the IMAGE ID?

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you assign a tag that is already in use to a new image (say, by building image `foo`, making a change in its Dockerfile, and then building `foo` again), the old image will lose that tag but will still stay around, even if all of its tags are deleted.  These older versions of your images are the untagged entries in the output of `docker images`, and you can safely delete them with `docker rmi <IMAGE HASH>` (though the deletion will be refused if there's an extant container still using that image).

Comment: @adam-beck ... this is the root cause of those untagged images the OP asks about

Answer (score 2):

Docker uses a file system called AUFS, which stands for Augmented File System. Pretty much each line of a Docker file will create a new image and when you stack or augment them all on top of each other you'll get your final docker image. This is essentially a way of caching, so if you change only the 9th line of your Docker file it wont rebuild the entire image set. (Well depends on what commands you have on your Docker file, if you have a `COPY` or `ADD` nothing after that point is cached for ex)

The final image will get tagged with whatever label it has, but all these intermediary images are necessary in order to create the final image so it doesn't make sense to delete them or prevent them from being created. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So the intermediary steps are the ones creating the untagged images? Why do I only seem to see them on my custom Dockerfiles? When I copy one from the hub I don't seem to get them. And when I say copy I mean the Dockerfile's contents; I'm not downloading the image.

Comment: have you tried `docker images -a` ? That would show everything

Comment: Note that `docker images -a` is the only way you would see intermediate images; if the OP isn't using that option, then my answer applies.